# MvvmLight template for C# WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have created a new WPF Application project in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop and added Nuget Package 'MvvmLight' to the solution. It created one folder called 'ViewModel' but according to http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1037/mvvm-light-wpf-model-view-viewmodel it should have created 4 folders ('Design','Model','Skins','ViewModel'). Is the one I've installed wrong/incomplete in some way?

I'm just after a decent MVVM model for a WPF application.

Answer (score 1):

From your link, the following steps are clearly stated:

> Step 1: Open Visual Studio and create a WPF Application and name it
> ‘WPF_MVVMLight_CRUD’. To this project, add the MVVM Light Libraries
> using NuGet Package as discussed in Installation section. **The project
> will add necessary libraries and the ‘ViewModel’ folder...**
>
> Step 2: In the project, **add a new folder with the name ‘Model’**. In
> this folder, add a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model...
>
> Step 3: Now **add a new folder called ‘Services’ and in this folder**, add
> a class file with the following...

And so on. This means the only folder it adds for you is the **ViewModels** one, and it provides a tutorial on how you can add the others yourself. Read the whole tutorial given in your link, it details the steps clearly. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Keyur Patel. In my defense it says just above figure 2: 'These project template by default provides the necessary libraries for the MVVM Light Framework with the project structure containing ViewModel classes, Models as shown in Figure 2:' which is incorrect.

Comment: That's fine. I work closely with MVVM, but I don't use toolkits like Light, instead I implement the structure myself using only ViewModels and Views (as do many others I think). If you have further questions, feel free to ask.